# Azure Data Factory Copy Snowflake to Azure blog storage ErrorCode 2200User configuration issue ErrorCode=SnowflakeExportCopyCommandValidationFailed

Tags: azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

Need help with this error.
ADF copy activity, Moving data from snowflake to azure blob storage delimited text.
I am able to preview the snowflake source data. I am also able to browse the containers via sink browse. This doesn't look like an issue with permissions.

```
ErrorCode=SnowflakeExportCopyCommandValidationFailed,
'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,
Message=Snowflake Export Copy Command validation failed: 
'The Snowflake copy command payload is invalid. 
Cannot specify property: column mapping,
Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Clear the mapping from copy activity, it worked.

Comment: Did not expect that clearing the imported mapping would fix the issue. I was wrong, clearing the imported mapping did fix the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
ErrorCode=SnowflakeExportCopyCommandValidationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Snowflake Export Copy Command validation failed: 'The Snowflake copy command payload is invalid. Cannot specify property: column mapping,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'"
```

**To resolve the above error, please check the following:**

- Please check the **copy command** you are using, it means the copy command you are using is not valid.
- To know more in detail about the **error**, try like below:

```
COPY INTO MYTABLE VALIDATION_MODE = 'RETURN_ERRORS' FILES=('result.csv');
```

Check if you have any issue with the data files before loading the data again.

- Try checking the storage account you are currently using and note that Snowflake doesn't support **Data Lake Storage Gen1.**
- Use the [COPY INTO](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location.html)  command to copy the data from the Snowflake database table into  Azure blob storage container.

**Note**:

> **Use the `blob.core.windows.net` endpoint for all supported types of Azure blob storage accounts, including Data Lake Storage Gen2.**

- Make sure to have either **`ACCOUNTADMIN`** role or a role with the global **`CREATE INTEGRATION`** privilege to run the below sample command:

```
copy into 'azure://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/unload/' from mytable storage_integration = myint;
```

By using the above command, you no need to include **credentials** to access the storage.

For more in detail, please **refer** below links:

[Unloading into Microsoft Azure — Snowflake Documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-unload-azure.html)

[COPY INTO < table> — Snowflake Documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#transformation-parameters)

Comment: It is a gen2 . I am using ADF to load, not using a copy into command.